HTTPS link in HTML Form being converted to HTTP with 443 port on load inside Iframe
Good afternoon everyone.  I am working to embed reports in our application with the report service provider of Domo.  I have created the following component.
import React from 'react';

const generateFormHtml = (actionUrl, embedToken) => (
    `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <form id="embedForm" action="${actionUrl}" method="post" target="embedFrame">
                <input type="hidden" name="embedToken" value="${embedToken}" />
            </form>
            <script>
                        document.getElementById("embedForm").submit();
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
    `
);

const generateDataUri = (html) => `data:text/html;charset=utf-8,${encodeURI(html)}`;

const ReportEmbedder = ({ actionUrl, embedToken }) => {
    const htmlContent = generateFormHtml(actionUrl, embedToken);
    const formDataUri = generateDataUri(htmlContent);

    return (
        <iframe
            className="panel embed-panel"
            name="embedFrame"
            src={formDataUri}
            allowtransparency="false"
        />
    );
};

export default ReportEmbedder;

That component is being called inside the main page inside the html
        /// actionUrl = 'https://public.domo.com/embed/pages/XXXXX'
        /// embedToken = 'full_length_embed_token'

            <div className="panel-container">
                    <ReportEmbedder
                            actionUrl={actionUrl}
                            embedToken={embedToken}
                        />
            </div>

My problem is that when the form renders, it seems to be converting the https url to http with a port associated.
HTTP ERROR 403 Access Denied
URI:    http://public.domo.com:443/embed/pages/XXXXXX
STATUS: 403
MESSAGE:    Access Denied
Does anyone have any idea how this could be happening or where to look?  I have a feeling it is just a configuration issue that I have overlooked but I have yet to find it.
I have worked with debugging to ensure that the URI states https through the entire process.  I have confirmed that in the generateDataUri step, the encoding is not over-riding the https setting.  I have had a few other engineers peer review but they have been just as confused as myself.
I am expecting the https link to continue so that the iframe loads the report from the endpoint.

This actually came down to an improperly formatted embedToken returned from the API.  There were additional characters that were unaccounted for.  The API endpoint I was posting to in turn returned an http response with a port associated.
If you ever run into this issue, ensure your Domo EmbedToken is properly formatted and save yourself days of time haha.  The Embed Token should not include any pointers or references other than the embedToken itself.

Your iframe, is a separate page and you need to ensure it is also logged into the site your trying to access.

Shouldn't the Iframe in this case just represent the response of the form?  If not, how would I go about adding the Iframe source to be the endpoint while also containing the form response?
